# What does this red pixel 'infection' mean?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cable, pixels

I was just using my PC with two screens. Suddenly a couple of red dots/pixels appeard on both screen, same position. I tried changing the cable, still red dots. They are stuck on the screen and don't move when I move windows around. It's easy to see with a light background.

Then I connected the monitor with a laptop (the PC and laptop both have Windows 10). It got worse! The laptop had more red dots and the PC still 4 (the laptop around 10).

The red dots don't flicker, don't change color, don't move, appeared randomly and I wasn't running a big program.
I don’t know if I'm the only one having this problem, but maybe someone can help me.

Comment: If these are LCD monitors, they may be stuck pixels. You may wish to look at this [How-To Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/130826/how-to-fix-a-stuck-pixel-on-an-lcd-monitor/) for some ideas on how to (potentially) fix this.

Comment: Are you running the screens cloned or stretched? Also, if you take a print screen, do the red pixels appear in the picture?

Comment: When you restart the computer, do they appear during boot?

Comment: If the dots appeared in the same place on two different screens, it isn't stuck pixels.  If it only does it with a certain application, the application may be producing a flawed image.  If it does it on all applications, it may be your graphics card.